# Adding a if block to Redux middleware

Tags: javascript, syntax, redux, react-redux

I'm adding an if block to the start of my src/services/middleware.js
But it does not look like I'm allowed to put `let questions` on line 43. 
How can I solve this with correct syntax? Should I create a global function named questions that returns the correct value? I was hoping I could keep it inside the function.

```
42 export const fetchIDPicker = (idnr, rnr, dato) =>
43     let questions;
44     if (idCheck(rnr) == 'car') {
45       questions = carQuestions;
46     } else if (idCheck(rnr) == 'travel') {
47       questions = travelQuestions;
48     }
49 
50     isDemo() ?
51         wrap(questions) :
52         apiCall(`ip-web/${id}/${rnr}`, Method.GET);
53
```

Comment: It's a syntax error. You need to put in `{` after `=>` in line 42.

Comment: Add your reply as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that arrow functions require `{}` when the function has a body and not just a return expression.

So change your code to this.

```js
export const fetchIDPicker = (idnr, rnr, dato) => {
  let questions;
  if (idCheck(rnr) == 'car') {
    questions = carQuestions;
  } else if (idCheck(rnr) == 'travel') {
    questions = travelQuestions;
  }

  isDemo() ?
    wrap(questions) :
    apiCall(`ip-web/${id}/${rnr}`, Method.GET);
  ...
}
```

**Edit** : Moving the comment to an answer as requested by OP.